# When adding multiple toolbarGroup in react pdftron the name of the toolbar group changed to option.toolbarGroup.toolbarGroup-AutoCount

Tags: reactjs, pdf, annotations, pdftron

When adding multiple toolbarGroup using createToolbarGroup in react PDFTron the name of the toolbar group changed to option.toolbarGroup.toolbarGroup-AutoCount, option.toolbarGroup.toolbarGroup-Drop.

```
instance.UI.createToolbarGroup({
        name:'Drop',
        dataElementSuffix: "Drop",
        useDefaultElements: true,
        children: [
           { 
               type: "toolGroupButton",
               toolGroup: "freeHandTools",
               dataElement: "freeHandToolGroupButton",
               title: "Count",
            
             },
            {
              type: "toolButton",
              toolName: "AnnotationCreatePerimeterMeasurement",
              dataElement:"ellipseAreaToolGroupButton",
            },
            {
              type: "customElement",
              render:()=><Count name='points' count ={pointsCount} />,
              onClick: (e) => {
                   
              },
            },
        ]
    })

instance.UI.createToolbarGroup({
        name: "Auto Count",
        dataElementSuffix: "AutoCount",
        useDefaultElements: false,
        children: [
          { type: "spacer" },
          {
            type: "toolButton",
            dataElement:"ellipseAreaToolGroupButton",
            toolName: "AnnotationCreateRectangle2",
            onClick:async()=>{
```

screenshot URL (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqMkf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contacting us regarding Webviewer.

We were able to reproduce the issue on our end. I just made a change internally and it's being reviewed by one of my colleagues at this moment. I will update this ticket once it's merged and available for testing.

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

The fix has been merged to our experimental build.

Please check the latest experimental build of Webviewer at https://www.pdftron.com/nightly/#experimental/2023-01-09/webviewer/.

You can download the build and give it a try. Please let us know if this resolve your issue, thank you.